# updatepanel refresh whole page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I use updatepanel in my page like this.
but when I run my app when I click on button that's refresh all of my page.
I do'nt know what I can do to solve this error.
even I use treeview in other page that when I get this error the treeview icon dont show.
please help me.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanl" runat="server" RenderMode="Block" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanl"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server" RenderMode="Block" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<Triggers>        
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />    
</Triggers>  
    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
   updPanl.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after three days I can find this problem today so I answer this question maybe this help to otherone.
I use routin in my app so webresource and scriptresouce could not load in asp page 
I use this code for do not route this resource

routeCollection.Add(new Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));